# Click event not work properly

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

In my website I wrote that code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){  LinkButton lbtnTopicAddress = new LinkButton();  lbtnTopicAddress.Click += lbtnSpecificTopic1_Click;}

protected void lbtnSpecificTopic1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){  Server.Transfer("~/SpecificTopic.aspx)"
```

}

But when I press on the link in run time, the caller doesn't go to the EventHandler method.

Why?

Note,
I wrote code like that in many pages in the same website but it work only in one page.

i added that code to many page in website but it worded only in one page every page has its specific code and no relation between them I hope you understand me thanks

I need help pleaseeeeeeee..........................

Comment: thats obviously not the complete code. what are you doing with the LinkButton your creating? Are you adding it to a table?

Comment: You are displaying the link button somewhere so that it can actually be clicked aren't you?  Use breakpoints as per my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to miss off a ;and a } here?

```
protected void lbtnSpecificTopic1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){  Server.Transfer("~/SpecificTopic.aspx)"
```

I assume you've put a breakpoint in to ensure it isn't being fired?

I'm not exactly sure but I've got a feeling that instead of Page_Load you need to use Page_Init so your code would look this this:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 LinkButton lbtnTopicAddress = new LinkButton();
 lbtnTopicAddress.Click += lbtnSpecificTopic1_Click;
}

protected void lbtnSpecificTopic1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Server.Transfer("~/SpecificTopic.aspx");
}
```

p.s. 5 mins formatting your code can work wonders when trying to debug

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the button to the controls on your page, or are you trying to find the "lbtnTopicAddress" control on your page?

Simply declaring the button won't do anything -- you have to get a reference to the control itself from the page.